# How do I pin and setup domain emails with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, domain

I have a domain name and I want  to use it as an email address.

I have a server and is currently hosting [alvarberglind.se](http://alvarberglind.se).

I want to have an email called "me@alvarberglind.se" and I want it to show up in my current gmail account. So I can choose if I want to send a mail from my new email adress or the old one. I have set up a gmail account and I can send email but I can't receive them.

I need a tutorial which tells me how I'm supposed to set up the gmail app to work with Crystone.
Crystone isn't an option in the list.

I'm using [crystone](http://crystone.com/).

Comment: Could you explain "to be pin into my gmail account"?

Answer (score 1):

Alvar,

For starters, you're going to need some MX records for your domain. Where they point will depend on who you have hosting your email.

If you're looking for an overall email solutions for your domain, you can use [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html). Otherwise, if you just want to have email sent to "me@alvarberglind.se" forwareded to your existing gmail account, your host (crystone) may have tools to do this for you.

Comment: I want to use google apps. Can you help?